# Extracting text from a String in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

Let's say I have a bunch of url strings in a pandas dataframe column, like...

https://www.tahoedailytribune.com/south-shore/...

And I am looking to grab the name between www. and .com. However, sometimes www. does not come up in the url/string and I cannot see a straight forward way to extract this. I have used length, such as [-8:] but I sometimes will have the www. to contend with and sometimes I wont.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

Answer (score 0):

This may need a couple of steps and some knowledge in regex.
1:  Use the urllib module to extract the `netloc` attribute (network location) of the url.
For *https://www.tahoedailytribune.com/south-shore/* that's *www.taheodailytribune.com*.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

# urlparse splits the url into separate components:
# parse_object: ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.tahoedailytribune.com', path='/south-shore/', params='', query='', fragment='')
parse_object = urlparse("https://www.tahoedailytribune.com/south-shore/")

# Get the network location
network_loc = getattr(parse_object, "netloc")
```

2: Now use a regex to grab everything between `www` and `.com`
This regex does not cater for sites using country specific suffixes, i.e `.co.uk`, `.com.au` etc

```
import re

# Pre compiled regex
# ?: means to not capture the group
# Regex permalink: https://regex101.com/r/yxrsr8/1
pattern = re.compile("^(?:www\.)?(\S+)(?:\.com)$")

# regex object if match else None
re_obj = re.match(pattern, network_loc)

if re_obj is not None:
  # site_name: tahoedailytribune
  site_name = re_obj.group(1)
else:
  print("Could not get site name")
```